# Magento - Product View Page shows nothing

Tags: magento, product

I have a website showing my products but when I click on the product to view the product details, I get an empty block. It displays all the CSS, sidebars, the headers but not the product itself. I've already done re-indexing, cache flushing, deleting files in the var folder, re-saved all configs, checking if product is on stock, enabled and visible.

I can see the products on the backend and I don't have any problems editing it, I also can see the products on homepage and other categories. Just when I click it on its url it returns an empty block.

I have worked and searched for a fix of this everywhere but I don't have any luck finding what suits best.

Comment: Please put some code to investigate further..

Comment: actually sir...there's no error showing on the page

Visit this link this is the actual issue that I'm getting...
http://bilibdeals.com/home/hair-rebond-w-treatment-cellophane-hair-cut-blow-dry.html
This is what's happening when I go to the direct url of the product
This is my problem...everything works fine but this

Comment: Did you by any chance modify any of the XML files in the layout folder?

Comment: Yeah!
I added a new <reference></reference>
But I reverted it back to it's previous version...(I deleted all the modifications already)

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this link and i can see that

```
<div class="col-main">....</div>
```

Is empty and it should show the product information.

So your problem is one of those things :

The layout is missing the block to show the product like ( wrong block type etc.. )

The block catalog/product_view has something wrong which prevent it from loading the product correctly ( might be date of the deal or enabled disabled status or qty in the products etc... )

To Debug this problem you have to do those steps :-

Enable logging in your magento store and check ( system.log , exception.log )

debug your block function (catalog/product_view)  to see if the product id is correct and if its loading the model correctly ?? Also debug the template catalog/product/view.phtml to check if its correctly loading the block type ?

```
get_class($this);
```

and see what class type is it.

Thank you

Comment: Hi sir!
Thanks for your answer....
I have already enabled system logging and exception logging, I saw all the errors that I might be encountering...

But I would like to know where exactly the folder should I look for (catalog/product/view.phtml) I can't seem to see it on my "frontend/default/MY_THEME/..." I also checked if the product is eneabled or have qty they are all fine. How can I know if it is in the wrong block type

THANK YOU SO MUCH! At least I can see some light now!

Comment: HI GUYS! EVERYTHINGS WORKING FINE!! THANK YOU!

Comment: @OhmelPaguirigan Can you share your solution and how you fixed it as I have the same problem